# How to upload files to an HTTP location using a python script

Tags: python, http

I am looking for a script which will upload files from a `unix` server to an HTTP location.

I want to use only these modules - `cookielib`, `urllib2`, `urllib`, `mimetypes`, `mimetools`, `traceback`

Comment: Show your attempts to get feedback. Specifically, where you are encountering a problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "an HTTP location"?  You can only upload a file to a server (which may then make the file available over HTTP), and how you do that depends on how the server is set up.  At the least, you'll probably need permissions on the server to put files there.

Comment: I would like to make question more clear

here http location mentioned is a common share folder link which can use by number of people by accessing through username/passwd. 

for ex: my target location has:
I have http:/commonfolder.mydomain.com/somelocation/345333 location 
I have username = someuid ,password = xxxxx

my source location has:
I have a my.txt file contains some data

I want to run shell or python script which will tranfer the file to target location mentioned above. so that many people can start using latest info I am uploading timely.

-shijo

Answer (score 0):

I would like to make question more clear

here http location mentioned is a common share folder link which can use by number of people by accessing through username/passwd.

for ex: my target location has:
I have http:/commonfolder.mydomain.com/somelocation/345333 location 
I have username = someuid ,password = xxxxx

my source location has:
I have a my.txt file contains some data

I want to run shell or python script which will tranfer the file to target location mentioned above. so that many people can start using latest info I am uploading timely.

-shijo